# class="jumbotron" in bootstrap not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is first time I am trying bootstrap. Everything seems to be in place except the class jumbotron is not working. Class container works and brings content in center but jumbotron which is suppose to give some background does not seems to work. (adding or removing this like class="jumbotron" has no effect on page.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>My first Bootstrap website!</h1>
        <p>This page will grow as we add more and more components from Bootstrap...</p>
      </div>

      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am attaching the [image] of ide so you can see my file tree. I checked it myself also and seems I have loaded everything correctly.

Update: redownloading the bootstrap solved the problem with exact same code. somehow my first download was not working correctly.

Comment: Did you get the bootstrap js file? Looks like you only got the css.

Comment: @Takendarkk <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> in line 23

Comment: Ok make a fiddle that demonstrates this then. My fiddle is working just fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/17rpLaqz/). Since you seem to have downloaded bootstrap you should check the developer console and make sure it is actually being applied to the page and the css classes are applying their attributes.

Comment: I'm guessing your .css or .js file is bad. Try redownloading it, or see if it works when you link to the hosted (instead of local) versions

Comment: @Parker Yes strngely redownloading the bootstrap with exact same index.html file solved the problem. This never happened before but seems like my first download was corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

without the ./ instead.

or the CDN:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the CDN?


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Redownloading the bootstrap and trying the same html file solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Jumbotron has become obsolete in bootstrap 5, so you cannot use it. Instead, you have to make your own version of jumbotron. You can use the following piece of code:

```
<div class="mt-4 p-5 bg-primary text-white rounded">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

in your HTML head.

Comment: You should also explain why this change is needed. Preferably with some link to documentation.